# Implementation of merge sort in Python

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I was working on an assignment and I was hoping to know if the merge sort algorithm I wrote in Python was not making any unnecessary computations.

```
def sort(some_list):

    if len(some_list) > 1:
        return merge(sort(some_list.__getslice__(0, len(some_list)/2)),\
         sort(some_list.__getslice__(len(some_list)/2, len(some_list))))
    else:
        return some_list


def merge(list_left, list_right):

    sorted_list = []

    while len(list_left) > 0 or len(list_right) > 0:

        if len(list_left) == 0:
            sorted_list.append(list_right.pop(0))

        elif len(list_right) == 0:
            sorted_list.append(list_left.pop(0))

        elif list_left[0] < list_right[0]:
            sorted_list.append(list_left.pop(0))

        else:
            sorted_list.append(list_right.pop(0))
    return sorted_list
```

I did some testing by calling time function to check how much time it took to merge a list of numbers of size 100,000 with different presortedness values (where a presortedness = 0 means it's completely random and presortedness = 1 means the list is already sorted).

I'm using a core i7 processor and working from PyCharm on an Ubuntu 14.04 OS.

This was my result:

> ```
> -------Test for Merge Sort----------------
> Presortedness = 0.00 (completely random)
> Time elapsed = 1.90153600 
>
>
> Presortedness = 0.25
> Time elapsed = 1.89535800 
>
>
> Presortedness = 0.50
> Time elapsed = 1.90894200 
>
>
> Presortedness = 0.75
> Time elapsed = 1.90660100 
>
>
> Presortedness = 1.00 (sorted)
> Time elapsed = 1.79297100
> ```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some helpful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually a terribly inefficient implementation... Some things to keep in mind:

1. Do not use the `__getslice__` method explicitly.  [It is a relic of a time long gone](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getslice__), and you only need to know about it if subclassing objects written in CPython. Not your case. And your code can be written in an infinitely more readable form as:

   ```
   def sort(some_list):
       if len(some_list) > 1:
          return merge(sort(some_list[:len(some_list)/2],
                        sort(some_list[len(some_list)/2:]))
       else:
           return some_list
   ```
2. Slicing a Python list creates a copy of the list. This is not what you typically want in a merge sort.  To avoid this, you can leave your original list unsliced, and pass around indices to the intervals being sorted and merged.  Such an in-place merge sort could be written as:

   ```
   def sort(list_, lo=None, hi=None):
       if lo is None:
           lo = 0
       if hi is None:
           hi = len(list_)
       if hi - lo <= 1:
           return
       mid = lo + (hi - lo) // 2
       sort(list_, lo, mid)
       sort(list_, mid, hi)
       merge(list_, lo, mid, hi)

   def merge(list_, lo, mid, hi):
       temp = list_[lo:mid]
       left = 0
       right = mid
       write = 0
       while left < mid - lo and right < hi:
           if list_[right] < temp[left]:
               list_[write] = list_[right]
               right += 1
           else:
               list_[write] = temp[left]
               left += 1
           write += 1
       if left < mid - lo
           list_[write:] = temp[left:]
   ```

   This is not a very Pythonic implementation.  It actually looks like C or Java translated line by line into Python.  But there is not much way around it.  Unless you simply do `sort(list_)`, which is the Pythonic way of getting a listy sorted.

Comment: Wow! You are completely right!! Thank you so much for the input!

Answer (score 2):

The main thing I see here is the constant use of '.pop' from array. You should try to avoid that because it moves (shifts) items in the array each time. I suggest avoiding changing the array at all.

Instead of

```
#you read the len of some_list 3 times.
some_list.__getslice__(0, len(some_list)/2)
some_list.__getslice__(len(some_list)/2, len(some_list))
```

I would use

```
mid = len(some_list) // 2  # measures the size of the list once for large lists
some_list[:mid] # left half
some_list[mid:] # right half
# makes your code more readable.
```

You can take these two out of the loop

```
if len(list_left) == 0:
   sorted_list.append(list_right.pop(0))

elif len(list_right) == 0:
   sorted_list.append(list_left.pop(0))
```

and add the rest of the larger list to the sorted_list and then change the condition of your loop to 'and' instead of 'or'.

Side Note:  I have seen other developers use '.extend()' and avoid using append and pop, but I'm not sure about performance implications using it that way.